# Visual Studio 2013 Hangs with error AppHangB1

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have an existing report, I made a change to the stored procedure that loads the data, adding 2 fields.  needed to refresh the data set.  when I try to refresh, VS hangs up and when I try to close I get a message stating that a problem caused this program to stop interacting with windows. Problem event name: AppHangB1

Answer (score 1):

After browsing for answers and finding different recommendations, restoring windows worked for me.

It seems that the problem was caused due to an automated windows update. My knowledge isn't that proper to know which part of it caused the issue. So I did this.

went to Start>System Restore

and then selected the previous restore point, and clicked on next, next until the system went on restoring.

It restarted the computer and when done, the program works just fine.